# How to produce 35mm lomo film noise/grain effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixelation

[image: 35mm lomo image]
<sup>Click on image for full size</sup>

There's a lot going on in this image. It's some 35mm lomo goodness. I am looking to produce some of the rich grain in my own digital images but am having trouble. Does anyone have any strategies or know of any tutorials to produce this kind of grainy effect.

I've been through the basics of generating noise but there has got to be some way to push those effects to an extreme to get something like what I've attached. Once I can get the grainy, pixelatedness I will need to go about producing bands, like the white one seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrast+Blur+Saturation+Grain

> Select your background copy layer and apply a blur –
>   Filter>Blur>Motion Blur
>
> Increase Contrast – Layer>New Adjustment Layer>Brightness and Contrast
>
> Increase Saturation – Layer>New Adjustment Layer>Hue and Saturation
>
> Create some grain by re-selecting your Background copy layer then do
>   the following – Filter>Texture>Grain

From http://www.photopatzer.com/2010/06/how-to-do-a-lomography-look-in-photoshop/

What you also have is scratches, which can be done with brushes. And the bands can either be created with brushes as well or done by hand. But all that doesn't go beyond the usual tutorials you can easily google.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am working on it. The motion blur is a good tip.

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole category "grain scan" products that are created for just this type of effect. They're produced by companies that actually scan exposed and developed films expressly for the purpose of capturing the grain pattern to replicate the effect of that specific film with a digital image. Most of these products are geared toward video production and are usually [very expensive](http://www.indiescans.com/35mm-film-grain/). Grain Snap was a company (formerly at grainsnap.com, now a link squater) that sold reasonably priced grain packages for still images, like their grains and Lomo light leak combo pack which would have been what you were looking for.

Comment: Looks like Grain Snap is out of business, grainsnap.com links now point to a link squatter.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched for digital grain for months, and as you say, almost all of them are really expensive (IndieScans, GorillaGrain, and others).

Grainsnap offer a reasonable price, but you can find real grain patterns even cheaper; I use those from Eyesmeal at film-effect-photoshop.com and they give professional results. Search for them, I think you can find a couple for free too.